# How to avoid downcasting?

Tags: java, object-oriented, type-casting

My question is about a special case of the super class Animal.

1. My `Animal` can `moveForward()` and `eat()`.
2. `Seal` extends `Animal`.
3. `Dog` extends `Animal`.
4. And there's a special creature that also extends `Animal` called `Human`.
5. `Human` implements also a method `speak()` (not implemented by `Animal`).

In an implementation of an abstract method which accepts `Animal` I would like to use the `speak()` method. That seems not possible without doing a downcast. Jeremy Miller wrote in [his article](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/12/26/downcasting-is-a-code-smell/) that a downcast smells.

What would be a solution to avoid downcasting in this situation?

Comment: Fix your model. Using existing taxonomical hierarchy to model a class hierarchy is usually wrong idea. You should pull your abstractions from existing code, not create abstractions and then try to fit code to it.

Comment: If you want Animals to speak, then the ability to speak is part of what makes something an animal:  http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html

Comment: moveForward? what about crabs?

Comment: Which item # is that in Effective Java, BTW?

Comment: @goldilocks searched the book but couldn't find the item I thought there was. Probably I read it somewhere else. I'll change this in my question. Though, I found this article about this matter: [link](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/12/26/downcasting-is-a-code-smell/)

Comment: @JeffO good point. I'll change speak() into writeEmail(), assuming that most of the Animals can't write at all.

Comment: @Barthelomeus No need; it wouldn't improve the question significantly and would invalidate lots of answers.

Comment: @Donal Fellows You'r right. Changed it back.

Comment: Some people  can't speak, so an exception is thrown if you try.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a method that needs to know whether the specific class is of type `Human` in order to do something, then you are breaking some [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), particularly :

- Open/closed principle - if, in the future, you need to add a new animal type that can speak (for example, a parrot), or do something specific for that type, your existing code will have to change
- Interface segregation principle - it sounds like you are generalizing too much. An animal can cover wide spectrum of species.

In my opinion, if your method expects a particular class type, to call it's particular method, then change that method to accept only that class, and not it's interface.

Something like this :

```
public void MakeItSpeak( Human obj );
```

and not like this :

```
public void SpeakIfHuman( Animal obj );
```

Comment: One could also create an abstract method on `Animal` called `canSpeak` and each concrete implementation must define whether or not it can "speak".

Comment: But I like your answer better.  Much complexity comes from trying to treat something like something that it is not.

Comment: @Brandon I guess, in that case, if it can not "speak", then throw an exception. Or just do nothing.

Comment: So you get overloading like this: `public void makeAnimalDoDailyThing(Animal animal) {animal.moveForward(); animal.eat()}` and `public void makeAnimalDoDailyThing(Human human) {human.moveForward(); human.eat(); human.speak();}`

Comment: Go all the way - makeItSpeak( ISpeakingAnimal animal ) - you can then have ISpeakingAnimal implements Animal. You could also have makeItSpeak( Animal animal ){ speak if instanceof ISpeakingAnimal }, but that has a faint smell.

Comment: How would I supposed to pass a Human to `MakeItSpeak`? `MakeItSpeak((Human)animal)`? Where is the difference?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not that you are downcasting - it's that you are downcasting to `Human`. Instead, create an interface:

```
public interface CanSpeak{
    void speak();
}

public abstract class Animal{
    //....
}

public class Human extends Animal implements CanSpeak{
    public void speak(){
        //....
    }
}

public void mysteriousMethod(Animal animal){
    //....
    if(animal instanceof CanSpeak){
        ((CanSpeak)animal).speak();
    }else{
        //Throw exception or something
    }
    //....
}
```

This way, the condition is not that the animal is `Human` - the condition is that it can speak. This means `mysteriousMethod` can work with other, non-human subclasses of `Animal` as long as they implement `CanSpeak`.

Comment: in which case it should take as argument an instance of CanSpeak instead of Animal

Comment: @Newtopian Assuming that that method doesn't need anything from `Animal`, and that all users of that method will hold the object they want to sent to it via a `CanSpeak` type reference(or even `Human` type reference). If that was the case, that method could have used `Human` in the first place and we wouldn't need to introduce `CanSpeak`.

Comment: Getting rid of the interface is not linked to being specific in the method signature you can get rid of the interface if and only if there is only Humans and will ever be only humans that "CanSpeak".

Comment: @Newtopian The reason we introduced `CanSpeak` in the first place is not that we have something that implements it(`Human`) but that we have something that uses it(the method). The point of `CanSpeak` is to decouple that method from the concrete class `Human`. If we didn't have methods that to treat things that `CanSpeak` differently, there would be no point in distinguishing things that `CanSpeak`. We don't create an interface just because we have a method...

Answer (score 2):

You could add Communicate to Animal. Dog barks, Human speaks, Seal.. uhh.. I don't know what seal does.

But it sounds like your method is designed to
    if(Animal is Human)
      Speak();

The question you may want to ask is, what is the alternative? Its hard to give a suggestion since I don't know exactly what you want to achieve. There are theoretical situations where downcasting/upcasting is the best approach.

Comment: The seal goes [ow ow ow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=RDjofNR_WkoCE&feature=player_detailpage&v=jofNR_WkoCE#t=31), but the fox is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the default implementation of `speak()` in the `AbstractAnimal` class would be:

```
void speak() throws CantSpeakException {
  throw new CantSpeakException();
}
```

At that point, you've got a default implementation in the Abstract class - and it behaves correctly.

```
try {
  thingy.speak();
} catch (CantSeakException e) {
  System.out.println("You can't talk to the " + thingy.name());
}
```

Yes, this means you've got try-catches scattered through the code to handle every `speak`, but the alternative to this is `if(thingy is Human)` wrapping all the speaks instead.

The advantage of the exception is that if you have another type of thing at some point that speaks (a parrot) you won't need to reimplement all of your tests.

Comment: I don't think this is a good reason to use exception (unless it is python code).

Comment: I won't down vote because this would technically work, but I really don't like this sort of design.  Why define a method at a parent level that the parent *cannot* implement?  Unless you know what type the object is (and if you did - you would not have this problem), you need to always use a try/catch to check for a completely avoidable exception.  You could even use an `canSpeak()` method to handle this better.

Comment: I have worked on a project that had a ton of defects originating from somebody's decision to rewrite a bunch of working methods to throw an exception because they are using an obsolete implementation.  He could have fixed the implementation, but chose instead to throw exceptions everywhere.  Naturally, we entered QA with hundreds of bugs.  So I am biased against throwing exceptions in methods that are not supposed to be called.  If they aren't supposed to be called, *delete them*.

Comment: Alternative to throwing an exception in this case may be doing nothing. After all, they can not speak :)

Comment: @Brandon there's a difference between designing it from the start with the exception vs retrofitting it in later.  One could also look at an interface with a default method in Java8, or not throwing an exception and just being silent.  The key point though is that to avoid needing to downcast, the function needs to be defined in the type being passed.

Answer (score 2):

> In an implementation of an abstract method which accepts Animals I would like to use the speak() method.

You have a few choices:

- Use reflection to call `speak` if it exists.  Advantage: no dependency on `Human`.  Disadvantage: there is now have a hidden dependency on the name "speak".
- Introduce a new interface `Speaker` and downcast to the interface.  This is more flexible than depending on a specific concrete type.  It has the disadvantage that you have to modify `Human` to implement `Speaker`.  This won't work if you can't modify `Human`
- Downcast to `Human`.  This has the disadvantage that you will have to modify the code whenever you want another subclass to speak.  Ideally you want to extend applications by adding code without repeatedly going back and changing old code.

Answer (score 1):

Downcasting is sometimes necessary and appropriate.  In particular, it's often appropriate in cases where one has objects that may or may not have some ability, and one wishes to use that ability when it exists while handling objects without that ability in some default fashion.  As a simple example, suppose a `String` is asked whether it is equal to some other arbitrary object.  For one `String` to equal another `String`, it must examine the length and backing character array of the other string.  If a `String` is asked whether it equals a `Dog`, however, it cannot access the length of the `Dog`, but it shouldn't have to; instead, if the object to which a `String` is supposed to compare itself isn't a `String`, the comparison should use a default behavior (reporting that the other object isn't equal).

The time when downcasting should be regarded as most dubious is when the object being cast is "known" to be of the proper type.  In general, if an object is known to be a `Cat`, one should use a variable of type `Cat`, rather than a variable of type `Animal`, to refer to it.  There are times when this doesn't always work, however.  For example, a `Zoo` collection might hold pairs of objects in even/odd array slots, with the expectation that the objects in each pair will be able to act upon each other, even if they cannot act upon the objects in other pairs.  In such a case, the objects in each pair would still have to accept a non-specific parameter type such that they could, *syntactically*, be passed the objects from any other pair.  Thus, even if `Cat`'s `playWith(Animal other)` method would only work when `other` was a `Cat`, the `Zoo` would need to be able to pass it an element of an `Animal[]`, so its parameter type would have to be `Animal` rather than `Cat`.

In cases where downcasting is legitimately unavoidable, one should use it without qualm.  The key question is determining when one can sensibly avoid downcasting, and avoiding it when sensibly possible.

Comment: In the string case, you should rather have a method `Object.equalToString(String string)`. Then you have `boolean String.equal(Object object) { return object.equalStoString(this); }` So, no downcast needed: you can use dynamic dispatching.

Comment: @Giorgio: Dynamic dispatching has its uses, but it's generally even worse than downcasting.

Comment: way dynamic dispatching generally even worse than downcasting? i thoughh it is other way around

Comment: @BryanChen: That depends on your terminology.  I don't think `Object` has any `equalStoString` virtual method, and I'll admit I don't know how the quoted example would even work in Java, but in C#, dynamic dispatch (as distinct from virtual dispatch) would mean that the compiler essentially has to do Reflection-based name lookup the first time a method is used on a class, which is distinct from virtual dispatch (which simply makes a call via a slot in the virtual method table which is required to contain a valid method address).

Comment: From a modelling point of view, I would prefer dynamic dispatching in general. It is also the object-oriented way of selecting a procedure based on the type of its input parameter(s).

Comment: Double/Dynamic Dispatch or Visitor Pattern does not need reflection to work - that's the whole point of it.

Comment: @Giorgio: Perhaps I was confused by the code in your comment; I don't know of any virtual method `equalToString` as part of `Object`, so what were you intending there?

Comment: @supercat: There's no such method in Java, it was just an example to illustrate the concept: You can define a method on a superclass and then use dynamic dispatch instead of if + downcasting. In this way you can avoid downcasting and your solution is more "object-oriented". Checking the type and casting is more "procedural" style.

Comment: @Giorgio: I would call that "virtual" rather than dynamic.  As I would expect the terms to be used, dynamic dispatching entails *searching for* a suitable function, while virtual dispatch entails invocation of a function whose entry point is stored in a known location.  If the hidden information associated with Java objects were stored as fields, a call like `someObject.equals(other)` would be equivalent to something like `someObject.typeInfo.methods[INDEX_OF_EQUALS](someObject, other);`.

Comment: @Giorgio: I should add that I very much like *virtual* dispatch; in cases where base types include the methods which are needed on derived types, virtual dispatch may avoid the need for downcasting.  On the other hand, the Interface Segregation Principle argues that base classes and interfaces should avoid defining methods which aren't applicable to all derived classes.  Personally I think that rule is often taken too far, with some rather unfortunate consequences, but unless one throws that rule totally out the window downcasting will often be unavoidable.

Comment: @supercat: With "dynamic dispatch" I mean that the actual implementation of an operation is chosen at runtime instead of compile time (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). I think your distinction only concerns different implementations of dynamic dispatch.